# How can I get only the date, but not the hour, of a date in a DataGridView filter?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a DataGridView, one of its columns being a date column with values like the following:

21/01/2020 09:14

20/01/2020 10:15

And I want to filter this DataView using a Date input from a textBox.

This is the code I have:

```
 string filter = "1 = 1";

 if (date_textBox.Text != "")
 {
     try
     {
         DateTime inputDate = DateTime.Parse(date_textBox.Text);

         filter += String.Format(" AND Convert(dateColumn, System.Date) = '{0}'", inputDate.ToShortDateString());
     }
     catch (FormatException)
     {
         //Invalid date, do nothing
     } //try-catch
 } //if

 myDataView.RowFilter = filter; // <=========Error in this line
```

I got an error when applying a filter to DataView because it doesn't understand System.Date. I have also tried Date, DateTime, System.DateTime and variations of the sort.

So, what's the type I need to convert this date column into? Or is there some function I can call in rowFilter that is gonna return only Date but not Time?

Comment: [`DateTime.TryParse` returns a `bool` indicating whether the parse succeeded or not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Right, is a DateTime.Parse what I have in my code

Comment: No, filter always starts with "1 = 1". Then it's added the " AND sth" if textbox has some text

Comment: @CR0N0S.LXIII What values is this property `myDataView.RowFilter` accepting? Correcct values, examples?

Comment: The allowed expressions for `RowFilter` are documented at [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @CR0N0S.LXIII it wasn't `DateTime.TryParse` until you edited. What's the error after you changed to `.Parse` instead of `.TryParse`?

Comment: RowFilter has worked with stuff like " AND dateColumn < '{0}'", being {0} a DateTime. It also works with primitive types like " AND some_id = {0}", with {0} an integer

Comment: I didn't changed the code. It was already DateTime.Parse. What was wrong was the question posted here, but my code was fine in that regard. That's what I meant by "it's .Parse what I have in my code"

Comment: So `RowFilter` must be in this case as `filter += String.Format("#{0}#", inputDate.Date);`. This from ["Birthdate < #1/31/82#", DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8) from @Heretic Monkey

Comment: Should you use rowfilter? I don't think there is an expression for RowFilter to achieve what you need. You could filter the rows using a simple Linq query and get a new DataTable, would that work for you? If so you could something like:
    var data = tbl.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(row => ((DateTime)row["dateColumn"]).Date == inputDate)
  .CopyToDataTable();

Comment: @yW0K5o You're missing the column name and operator in that expression.

Comment: @yW0K5o, that wouldn't work when date column has time information.

Comment: it is just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using RowFilter is a MUST then this would work (I don't recommend but would work):

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(date_textBox.Text, out DateTime inputDate))
{
     var filter = $" (dateColumn >= '#{inputDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}#'"+
                  $" And dateColumn < '#{inputDate.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}#')";

 myDataView.RowFilter = filter;
}
```

If generating a filtered DataTable from the existing DataTable would do, I prefer this approach:

```
var data = tbl.AsEnumerable() 
 .Where(row => ((DateTime)row["dateColumn"]).Date == inputDate)
 .CopyToDataTable();
```